# how to make sure memory for objects like LOH get released at end of request in case of Dependency Injection asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, memory, dependency-injection, garbage-collection

I am using asp.net core 3.1 razor pages,

I want to release memory for the objects used at end of request,

business classes and repository classes are used in dependency injection with scoped and transient lifetime are used, There are some Large heap objects must be getting created as I am using list, data tables for storing more than 10k records.

Initially when request starts memory used is 150 mb once request start processing and moves to completion memory used exceeds 2-3 gb, when request is completed I want to make memory drop to again 150 mb, currently I do not see drop in memory when request is completed

What are things I can take care in case of c# to make sure memory will get released for objects at end of request.

Comment: The first thing is make sure you create List within your request scope, and not in global one, so garbage collector will take care of this. Also you can perform List.Clear()

Comment: `List.Clear()` won't help with the LOH if the object is already eligible for GC.

Comment: "when request is completed I want to make memory drop to again 150 mb". Where are you looking to see the memory usage? Note that the Windows Task Manager is unreliable because it doesn't reflect that actual memory on all managed heaps. You should analyze performance using Windows Performance Counters instead.